# Can't declare initial ReduxToolkit slice state with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

There is an official documentation, that I follow to create slice with TS ->
[RTK usage with TS](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript), which describes how we can give type for our state.

[image]

But when you do so, there is a problem in my reducers, they expect my state to contain only status key, but not data.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here?
There is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-forked-qbzl5x?file=/src/store.ts), where you can see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general problem regarding TypeScript union types, as your first option `{ status: 'loading' }` does not have a `data` property.  You can get rid of this particular error, `Property 'data' does not exist on type`, by including `data?: never`.

```
type SliceState = { state: 'loading'; data?: never } | { state: 'finished'; data: string }
```

But you will continue to have problems.  Here's why:

Your union type says that the values of `state` and `data` must match.  You cannot directly assign to either property because you risk creating an invalid state which does not meet the constraints of the union.

If the value of your `state` variable is `{ state: 'loading' }`, then assigning `state.data = action.payload` will create a new value of `{ state: 'loading'; data: 'some string' }` which is not assignable to `SliceState`.

You have a few options here:

1. Use a less restrictive state type, for example:

```
type SliceState = { state: 'loading' | 'finished'; data?: string };
```

2. Use an `as` assertion, for example:

```
(state as any).data = action.payload;
```

3. Return a new state from your reducer rather than modifying the draft.  This way you ensure that the state meets the constraints of the union type.

```
dataReceived: (state, action) => {
   return { state: 'finished, data: action.payload };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the error says that `state.data` doesn't exist on the first possibility of `SliceState`.

If you want `data` to be available, you could do

```
type SliceState =
  | { state: "loading"; data: undefined }
  | { state: "finished"; data: string };
const initialState: SliceState = { state: "loading", data: undefined };
```

Here is a fork of your [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-forked-jtt1bh?file=/src/store.ts:82-254).

However, I don't think it is a good idea to type `SliceState` like so, you should instead type it

```
type SliceState = { state: "loading" | "finished"; data?: string };

const initialState: SliceState = { state: "loading" };

const testSlice = createSlice({
  name: "test1",
  initialState, // type SliceState is inferred for the state of the slice
  reducers: {
    changeState: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
    }
  }
});
```

And in your app make sure that `data` is defined when you use it, instead or relying on the `status` attribute.